# why when im using files <- dir(path="F/My files/specification/a",all.files = TRUE,full.names = TRUE) files is empty?

Tags: r

Why when I'm using

```
files <- dir(path="F/My files/specification/a",all.files = TRUE,full.names = TRUE)
```

`files` is empty?

Comment: try remove space in `My files` or put `_`

Comment: `:` missing after F ?

Answer (score 0):

Is `F` a directory inside your working directory (you can check this with `dir(getwd())`?
I assume it is not and you have to write the full path to your files.
If `F` is your hard disk and you are working with windows, the path may be `"F:/My files/specification/a"`.

Comment: Thank u so much. I forgot write : , it was big mistake. Now its working.